# Subclassing .NET Chart Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created a subclass of a System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart. In the constructor I have set up a default chart area and series:

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea chartArea1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();

chartArea1.AxisX.Title = "Time (s)";
chartArea1.AxisY.Title = "Value(%)";
chartArea1.Name = "MainChartArea";
series1.ChartArea = "MainChartArea";
series1.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.FastLine;
series1.Name = "Series1";
Series.Add(series1);
```

I have added a collection of functions to the subclass to use ChartAreas[0]. This is all fine.

Now in VS2010 I create a new control, go to the toolbox and add my custom chart control. What seems to happen is VS copies my default chart area and series to the parent controls's InitializeComponent function.

When I execute the code there is an exception inside the parent control's InitializeComponent function saying that the subclass of the chart already has a chart area with the name "MainChartArea" and already has a series with the name "Series1".

If I now edit the parent control InitializeComponent code to change the names it builds and runs just fine.

However, if I now go back and make any change to the parent control VS re-copies the default chart area and series settings again, resulting in the same problem.

I know that I can simply remove the code from the parent control's InitializeComponent function, but then I don't get a visual representation in the designer of my chart control and it seems bad practice to edit it manually.

What is the correct way to subclass a Chart control so that I can set up the area and series on the subclass?

Comment: Controls with fancy designers, like Chart, tend to misbehave when you derive from them.  Their designer can't tell the difference between the series you added in the constructor vs any series you added with the designer.  So it dutifully serializes the one you created in the constructor as well.  Pretty unlikely you want that when you created a series in the designer.  And worse, your constructor *also* runs at runtime, now you have *two* series you don't want.  Fixing this requires tinkering with the designer.  Totally unpractical, it is undocumented and very elaborate.  Just stop helping.

Comment: Thanks. I feared as much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish your goal, you will need to define a class derived from `System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner` and assign that as the Designer of your custom Chart class.  All creation of the initial `ChartArea`, `Series`, and `Legend` should be performed in the `ControlDesigner` class method `InitializeNewComponent` instead of the custom Chart's constructor.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    [System.ComponentModel.Designer(typeof(MyChartDesigner))]
    public class MyChart : Chart
    {
    }

    // Add Project Ref:  System.Design
    internal class MyChartDesigner : System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner
    {
        public override void InitializeNewComponent(System.Collections.IDictionary defaultValues)
        {
            if ((this.Control != null) && this.Control is Chart)
            {
                Chart control = (Chart)this.Control;
                if ((control.ChartAreas.Count == 0) && (control.Series.Count == 0))
                {
                    ChartArea chartArea1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();
                    Series series1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();

                    chartArea1.AxisX.Title = "Time (s)";
                    chartArea1.AxisY.Title = "Value(%)";
                    chartArea1.Name = "MainChartArea";
                    series1.ChartArea = "MainChartArea";
                    series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
                    series1.Name = "Series1";

                    control.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
                    control.Series.Add(series1);
                }
            }
            base.InitializeNewComponent(defaultValues);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to be able to change a few properties, a work around might be to create a `UserControl` that contains the chart and then add a few properties to that control that modify the chart as desired. In practice, this would be useful only if you have a lot of common changes but very few specific changes.

Alternatively, you might have an helper class that you would call when the form is load and would apply some changes at run-time. The designer won't show the actual look of the chart.

As mentioned in a comment, not all controls behave as desired (in the designer) when you derive from them. It might be possible to fix some problem by writing a lot of code to handle design-time edition and serialization but I have essentially not experience with that.

Usually, if a control has to manage child controls or lists, deriving from that control might cause problems... For simple controls, often it might just be a bit less optimal because some properties might be set twice...